# How to add audio to transitions in Final Cut

Tags: audio, final-cut-pro-x, transitions

this question is probably asked already, but as I am not pro video editor I do not know how to ask properly.
My question is: how can I add audio transition? I don't mean just fade in or out, I mean actual sounds synced with the visual transition
When transition occures the proper audio transition plays.
I can only do it manualy, but it is not the point.
For example, when the shot changes I want the circle transition with the corresponding sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is indeed very confusing.  What, exactly, is the corresponding sound to the circle transition?  Is it a cricket?  Is it a car honk?  Is it the sound of a particular church bell ringing?  Is it the sound of a glacier melting?  And what about the sound of a triangular transition?  Or the sound of a vertical vs. horizontal wipe?

These questions are rhetorical; there is no sound associated with these transitions, other than the sounds you creatively choose to associate with them.  Thus, the answer to your question is that you do need to choose those audio transition sounds, and audio transitions, manually.

Comment: I thought that there are transitions with built in sounds.

Comment: iMovie does this: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH3322?locale=en_US.  It is the craft of the magician to make it appear as if magic exists.  It is the craft of the filmmaker to make it appear as if every transition is so natural that it doesn't even look like editing, and that every sound is so natural that it doesn't sound like an effect, but part of the film itself.